# Get percentage of matching strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two string to match and get the percentage of matching.

Given:

```
String 1: John Smith Makde

String 2: Makde John Smith
```

Used the following user defined scalar function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching]
(
    @string1 NVARCHAR(1000)
    ,@string2 NVARCHAR(1000)
)
RETURNS INT

--WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @levenShteinNumber INT

    DECLARE @string1Length INT = LEN(@string1), @string2Length INT = LEN(@string2)
    DECLARE @maxLengthNumber INT = CASE WHEN @string1Length > @string2Length THEN @string1Length ELSE @string2Length END

    SELECT @levenShteinNumber = [dbo].[f_ALGORITHM_LEVENSHTEIN] (@string1  ,@string2)

    DECLARE @percentageOfBadCharacters INT = @levenShteinNumber * 100 / @maxLengthNumber

    DECLARE @percentageOfGoodCharacters INT = 100 - @percentageOfBadCharacters

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @percentageOfGoodCharacters

END
```

Function calling:

```
SELECT dbo.f_GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching('John Smith Makde','Makde John Smith')
```

Output:

```
7
```

But when I give both the string as same with same position:

```
SELECT dbo.f_GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching('John Smith Makde','John Smith Makde')
```

Output:

```
100
```

**Expected Result**: As the both strings words are same but with different sequence I want 100% matching percentage.

```
100
```

Comment: You will need to post the `[dbo].[f_ALGORITHM_LEVENSHTEIN]` function as well as this seems to be doing the processing of the two strings?

Comment: What is the expected result from `SELECT dbo.f_GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching('John Smith Makde','John Smith Makde')`?

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: If I get this correctly, you want a result of 100% if the *fragments* are the same (let's say: `John Smith Makde == Makde John Smith`)? You can 1) split this, sort it alphabetically and compare such *normalized* strings or 2) split it and do an *each-with-each* and compute an average percentage... But please clearify your needs first.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, My bad, I have added expected result.

Comment: @Shnugo, My bad, Edited with expected result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this for millions of rows again and again will be a nightmare... I'd add another column (or a `1:1` related side table) to permantently store a *normalized* string. Try this:

--Create a mockup table and fill it with some dummy data

```
CREATE TABLE #MockUpYourTable(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeName VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO #MockUpYourTable VALUES('Makde John Smith')
                                  ,('Smith John Makde')
                                  ,('Some other string')
                                  ,('string with with duplicates with');
GO
```

--Add a column to store the normalized strings

```
ALTER TABLE #MockupYourTable ADD NormalizedName VARCHAR(1000);
GO
```

--Use this script to split your string in fragments and re-concatenate them as canonically ordered, duplicate-free string.

```
UPDATE #MockUpYourTable SET NormalizedName=CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT LOWER(SomeName) AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
                                            .query(N'
                                                    for $fragment in distinct-values(/x/text())
                                                    order by $fragment
                                                    return $fragment
                                                    ').value('.','nvarchar(1000)');           
GO
```

--Check the result

```
SELECT * FROM #MockUpYourTable

ID  SomeName                            NormalizedName
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Makde John Smith                    john makde smith
2   Smith John Makde                    john makde smith
3   Some other string                   other some string
4   string with with duplicates with    duplicates string with

--Clean-Up
GO
DROP TABLE #MockUpYourTable
```

**Hint** Use a trigger `ON INSERT, UPDATE` to keep these values synced.

Now you can use the same transformation against your strings you want this to compare with and use your former approach. Due to the re-sorting, identical fragments will return 100% similarity.

Comment: Great! Any fastest matching percentage for large data(example `table1` has `few rows` and `table2` has more than `10 million rows`)?

Comment: @MAK, you must know whether to search for **matching** or for a measure of *nearness*. With millions of rows, it will be important **how often an expensive computation must be executed**. Whenever you can pre-compute values (like the normalized names) it will help extraordinarily. You might try to reduce the rows by excluding those, which are **not similar** (by length, by `SOUNDEX`, whatever). But the computation of a percentage will have to be computed at run-time. This must get slow with *10 million rows*...

Comment: Can I get some more optimization on given approach of normalization? As its taking more than 5 min for 10 million records to update.

Comment: @MAK, First of all: Pleae avoid follow up questions, rather start a new question and place a link here. This will pull much more attraction and it keeps SO clean in *1 issue - 1 question*. Again your needs are not fully clear: The *normalization* pointed out in my answer should be a *one time action* and should be persisted in an additional column or a side table. The `XML / XQuery` approach is not fast... You might move to SQL-Server 2016 and use `STRING_SPLIT()` or use a CLR-function. But with 2008-R2 you are limited... My suggestion: Start a new question with more details and place a link.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for the question. It appears you are trying to determine how similar two names are. It's hard to determine how you are doing that. I'm very familiar with the Levenshtein Distance for example but don't understand how you are trying to use it. To get you started I put together two ways you might approach this. This won't be a complete answer but rather the tools you will need to do whatever you're trying.

To compare the number of matching "name parts" you could use [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) like this:

```
DECLARE 
  @String1 VARCHAR(100) = 'John Smith Makde Sr.',
  @String2 VARCHAR(100) = 'Makde John Smith Jr.';

SELECT COUNT(*)/(1.*LEN(@String1)-LEN(REPLACE(@string1,' ',''))+1)
FROM
(
  SELECT      s1.item
  FROM        dbo.delimitedSplit8K(@String1,' ') AS s1
  INTERSECT
  SELECT      s2.item
  FROM        dbo.delimitedSplit8K(@String2,' ') AS s2
) AS a
```

Here Im splitting the names into atomic values and counting which ones match. Then we divide that number by the number of values. 3/4 = .75 for 75%; 3 of the four names match.

Another method would be to use [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) like so:

```
DECLARE 
  @String1 VARCHAR(100) = 'John Smith Makde Sr.',
  @String2 VARCHAR(100) = 'Makde John Smith Jr.';

SELECT (1.*f.L-f.MM)/f.L
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    MM = SUM(ABS(s1.C-s2.C)), 
    L  = CASE WHEN LEN(@String1)>LEN(@string2) THEN LEN(@String1) ELSE LEN(@string2) END
  FROM
  (
    SELECT s1.token, COUNT(*)
    FROM   samd.NGrams8k(@String1,1) AS s1
    GROUP BY s1.token
  ) AS s1(T,C)
  JOIN 
  (
    SELECT s1.token, COUNT(*)
    FROM   samd.NGrams8k(@String2,1) AS s1
    GROUP BY s1.token
  ) AS s2(T,C)
  ON  s1.T=s2.T  -- Letters that are equal
  AND s1.C<>s2.C -- ... but the QTY is different
) AS f;
```

Here we're counting the characters and substracting the mismatches. There are two (one extra J and one extra S). The longer of the two strings is 20, there are 18 characters where the letter and qty are equal. 18/20 = .9 OR 90%.

Again, what you are doing is not complicated, I would just need more detail for a better answer.

Comment: I am expecting 100%(1.000) for the given strings but from second method I am getting `NULL` output.

Comment: If I remove condition `s1.C<>s2.C` will get it, can I do same for between two tables columns for example table1 has few rows and table2 has more than 10 million rows?