# Get matching string with the percentage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following details of the data:

Table 1: `Table1` is of small in size around `few records`.

Table 2: `Table2` is having `50 millions` of rows.

**Requirement**: I need to match the any string column from `table1` to `table2` for example `name` column to `name` and get the percentage of matching (note column can be any, maybe address or any string column which have multiple words in a single cell).

**Sample data:**

```
create table table1(id int, name varchar(100), address varchar(200));

insert into table1 values(1,'Mario Speedwagon','H No 10 High Street USA');
insert into table1 values(2,'Petey Cruiser Jack','#1 Church Street UK');
insert into table1 values(3,'Anna B Sthesia','#101 No 1 B Block UAE');    
insert into table1 values(4,'Paul A Molive','Main Road 12th Cross H No 2 USA');
insert into table1 values(5,'Bob Frapples','H No 20 High Street USA');    

create table table2(name varchar(100), address varchar(200), email varchar(100));

insert into table2 values('Speedwagon Mario ','USA, H No 10 High Street','mario@gmail.com');
insert into table2 values('Cruiser Petey Jack','UK #1 Church Street','jack@gmail.com');
insert into table2 values('Sthesia Anna','UAE #101 No 1 B Block','Aanna@gmail.com');    
insert into table2 values('Molive Paul','USA Main Road 12th Cross H No 2','APaul@gmail.com');
insert into table2 values('Frapples Bob ','USA H No 20 High Street','BobF@gmail.com');
```

**Expected Result**:

```
    tbl1_Name               tbl2_Name           Percentage  
--------------------------------------------------------
Mario Speedwagon        Speedwagon Mario    100
Petey Cruiser Jack      Cruiser Petey Jack  100
Anna B Sthesia          Sthesia Anna        around 80+
Paul A Molive           Molive Paul         around 80+
Bob Frapples            Frapples Bob        100
```

**Note**: Above given is just sample data to understand, I have `few records` in `table1` and `50 millions` in `table2` in actual senario.

**My Try**:

**Step 1**: As suggested by [Shnugo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670113/get-percentage-of-matching-strings/54689301?noredirect=1#comment96267200_54689301) have normalize data and stored in the same table's.

For table1:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD Name_Normal VARCHAR(1000);
GO

--00:00:00 (5 row(s) affected)
UPDATE table1 
SET Name_Normal=CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT LOWER(name) AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
                .query(N'
                        for $fragment in distinct-values(/x/text())
                        order by $fragment
                        return $fragment
                        ').value('.','nvarchar(1000)');           
GO
```

For table2:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD Name_Normal VARCHAR(1000);
GO

--01:59:03 (50000000 row(s) affected)
UPDATE table2 
SET Name_Normal=CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT LOWER(name) AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
                .query(N'
                        for $fragment in distinct-values(/x/text())
                        order by $fragment
                        return $fragment
                        ').value('.','nvarchar(1000)');           
GO
```

**Step 2**: Create Percentage calculation function using [Levenshtein distance in Microsoft Sql Server](http://levenshtein.blogspot.com/)

**Step 3**: Query to get the matching percentage.

```
--00:00:33 (23456 row(s) affected)
SELECT t.name AS [tbl1_Name],t1.name AS [tbl2_Name],
       dbo.ufn_Levenshtein(t.Name_Normal,t1.Name_Normal) percentage 
       into #TempTable
FROM table2 t
INNER JOIN table1 t1 
ON CHARINDEX(SOUNDEX(t.Name_Normal),SOUNDEX(t1.Name_Normal))>0 

--00:00:00 (23456 row(s) affected)
SELECT * 
FROM #TempTable 
WHERE percentage >= 50
order by percentage desc;
```

**Conclusion**: Getting expected result but it's taking around `2 hours` for normalizing `table2` as mentioned in comment in above query. Any suggestion for better optimization at `step 1` for `table2`?

Comment: Why is it important how long the normalizing action takes? This should be a *one-time-action*... Just imagine the necessary work to lower-case 50mio strings, split them in fragments and re-concatenate this in sorted order... As told you in the other question: It would really help to move to SQL-Server 2016 for `STRING_SPLIT()`. And you might try to shift this work to a CLR-function. The XML-splitter with the `XQuery`-based normalizing must be slow...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into DQS (Data Quality Services)?
Depends on your SQL version, it comes with the installation file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/data-quality-services/data-matching?view=sql-server-2017